# Manage/remove Azure AD selection at my login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to manage/remove Azure AD at my selection (top right)? I no longer work for this company who owns those AD.

[image: portal.azure.com]

Answer (score 1):

Your account is probably still a member in those directories. They have to remove it from the directory for them to disappear from the selection list.

Comment: So if they never remove my account from their AD then it will be on my list?

Comment: Yes. Currently there is no option in the portal to hide directories.